# FIM 2010 Delta Import for Multi-value attribute issue (need-full-object)

Tags: import, authorization, identity, multivalue, delta

I need to do Delta Import on a multivalue attribute of an object. So my delta configuration in FIM sync is using "Attribute level change type synchronization", my delta view is returning "Modify_Attribute".

It is working fine when a value is removed from the existing multivalue attribute and when a value is added to an existing multivalue attribute.

However, when the object is not yet imported in the CS, and I do delta import, I have the error "need-full-object". Which to me, it does make sense since i am intending to modify an attribute of non-existing object in the connector space.

My solution is to adjust my delta view that for newly added records, i will return "Add" as DeltaOperation, and for newly deleted records, i will return "Modify_Attribute". So far it is working but it doesn't feel right to me since 2 or more new values also will be seen as Add, which in fact it is just a modify and I'm not sure if there is a performance impact.

For me, FIM should automatically detect that this object does not exist yet in the CS and then perform Add operation. Otherwise, i will stick to my existing solution or revise my delta view to determine which "Add" is truly "Add" or "Modify_Attribute". Are there any better solution to this, or perhaps hot fixes from any latest versions?

Thanks! Hoping experts would help me.